# Upper bound of a set and a sequence

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

If the excercise says:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be an accumulation value of the real sequence $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and an upper bound of the set $\{a_{n}\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N} \}$.

Does is mean that $a$ is also the upper bound of the real sequence $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: You literally asked the exact same question two hours ago.

Comment: It's the same problem but it's a different question. Sorry, I want to confirm something so I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every convergent sequence is a bounded sequence, that is the set {$a_n : n ∈ \mathbb{N}$} is
bounded.